# How a web service should report an error

Tags: web-services

Right now when my webservice found an error like cant conenct to remote database or the record you are looking for isnt found i define a special return value.

For example:

My webservice return distance as integer, the i return negative values for some errors. (-100, -200, etc)

But if my webservice return a Dataset "employee" then i return a Dataset "error" with (ErrorID, Description)

First example is more natural for me, but the second because i change the dataset name i feel a litle more worried.

The main thing is i always make a proper document so webservice consumer know how to handle **special** return values.

So Im looking for what should be the best practice.

Comment: Is this a SOAP or Rest service? Better to encapsulate your response data in a wrapper container of some sort that has the call results information.

Comment: Do you have a sample of a wrapper container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a simple wrapper class containing the data (payload) and an error string (preferably localised) or integer. Have your client side JavaScript check if the `Error` property is non null or greater than 0 and take the appropriate action in that case as it indicates an error. Otherwise, process the payload from the `Data` property as normal.

An example in C#:

```
public class WebMethodReturn<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```